# excel 2010 vba pivot table report filter update

Tags: vba, excel, filter, pivot-table

I have 16 pivot tables on the same sheet, "Analytics Admin", I recorded and cleaned up the macro below (the code right before updates the info the pivot tables source). It's basically the same code 16 times, the only thing that changes is the pivot table name ( MSP, MSP30, FSP, FSP30, etc). Is it possible to change the report filter for all the pivot tables at once?

```
Worksheets("Analytics Admin").Activate

'refreshes all data, clears all filters then filters 0 and blanks out of all custom range pareto pivot tables

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MSP").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MSP").PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MSP").PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MSP").PivotFields("count")
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("MSP").PivotCache.Refresh

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FSP").PivotCache.Refresh
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FSP").PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FSP").PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FSP").PivotFields("count")
        .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("FSP").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: have you considered looping through all pivot tables on the sheet?

Comment: somehow I've managed to never use loops before could you elaborate a little?

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of (not tested, just typed into here)

```
    dim ws as Worksheet
    set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Analytics Admin")
    dim pt as PivotTable
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
'            Debug.Print Pivot.Name
            pt.PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters
            pt.PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True

            With pt.PivotFields("count")
              .PivotItems("0").Visible = False
              .PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
            End With
            pt.PivotCache.Refresh
            pt.refreshTable
            pt.Update
        Next
```

Comment: this code partially works however for some reason, certain pivot tables throw and error at `pt.PivotFields("count").ClearAllFilters` and others at `pt.PivotFields("count").ShowAllItems = True`. runtime 1004 unable to get the PivotFeilds property of the PivotTable class.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2010 or later, and most (hopefully all) of these Pivots share the exact same data source, you can do this with little or no looping. Simply set up a Slicer on the "count" field and then connect it to all the PivotTables (right click on the Slicer, and select "Report Connections". Then you only need to run the code on one of those PivotTables, and all the others will update automatically.

You can hide the Slicer somewhere if you don't want users to click it.

Comment: I like this idea. I am using 2010 but so far I've only been able to connect 2 pivot tables and that was mostly by accident. I cannot seem to connect all the tables on the page thru any means.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Slicers can only be connected to PivotTables that share the same PivotCache (i.e. they share the exact same data source). I'll add that to my answer. If *most* of your pivots do share the same data source, add the slicer to one of those, connect it to the others, and then use code to sync one of those to pivots on other caches. Otherwise, Teylyn's code will be the best way to go.

Comment: ok that makes sense, the slicer that did have multiple pivots was on the one pivot table using dummy data from another data set. I will try and merge the source data, and give this another go